# Is there any performance issue if my table has more than 200 columns in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, database-normalization

I have a master table where i have my clients listed, based on this table i am displaying all the data in all the pages i have, so in master table i have about 200+ columns to make every thing dynamic by choosing yes/no to display some sections.

Each client has their own preferences, when my product started i used 40 columns in this but created 200+ columns when new client asking us to do new things and these things needs to hide for old clients, i am querying once in every page to get data from this table. If i keep on increasing upto 250 columns, will I get any performance issues?

I know i should use normalization here to make it simpler, but time being we went like this. Please suggest what i should do here?

Comment: I'd suggest looking into json column to store dynamic data such as preferences, that way your client preferences can grow or shrink without having to create/remove columns

Comment: Why downvotes? Asking a question which i don't know has any issue? I am learning the things here not playing.

Comment: Thank you har2vey, yes that is a nice idea to setup in initial stage but now i have nothing to change, i should continue with the same way it built as per the norms. Just wanted to know where i should stops adding new columns?

Comment: I have only 1200 rows in this table.

Comment: You should not have columns like e.g. `pref_0` to `pref_19` in your table, these would be better fetched with a second query from a separate table.

Comment: Adder, No I am not using like same prefix you mentioned. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

200 columns should not be a problem for any SQL server. What could cause problems is the number of queries. Let's say 1000 queries / sec might cause problems.

The rest depends on your specific server setup.

Comment: Thank you H.Boe, I am running a query always to fetch one row at a time because need to fetch one client's record always. It is not 1000/sec but server hit this table always to fetch the logged in client information.